# Three.js gradient across multiple faces

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to build a `HSV cylinder` in `three.js`, and I'm having a hard time mapping the gradient to the faces. I thought that I could just create my object like this:

[image: Wireframe]

However, the gradients – especially on the red quad going downwards – do not look smooth. It makes sense, but I don't know how to fix it.

[image: Real]

I really just want to create a quad and specify the corner vertex colors, but `Face4` is gone, and all examples use this.

Is there any way to create a gradient that goes across a rectangular face (or combinations of faces)? How do I need to think about gradients that need to run over multiple faces?

Answer (score 1):

"More triangles" seems to be the answer here.

[image]

[image]